# dask: return None or empty from delayed task

Tags: python, pandas, dask

I would like to return an empty dataframe/ None from a set of delayed tasks where parsing fails, e.g.;

```
import dask.dataframe as dd
import dask.delayed

def _read(self, filename):
    try:
        df = pd.read_csv(filename, sep=';', decimal=',', encoding='latin1', index_col=False)
        return df
    except BaseException as e:
        return pd.DataFrame()


tasks = []
for root, dirs, files in os.walk(os.path.join(self._path, "files")):
    for file in files:
        tasks.append(dask.delayed(_read, pure=True)(os.path.join(root, file)))

ddf = dd.from_delayed(tasks)
```

One or two of the files fail being parsed, and at the moment I receive a metadata mismatch. I could return a dataframe with the dask dataframe metadata specified, but just wondering if there's a better way.

Comment: Can you make a dataframe with the right columns/dtypes but zero rows, perhaps from the first file that parses successfully?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Going with the comment from @mdurant, it's not as easy as you'd expect to copy a dataframe maintaining types, but this seems to work. This wouldn't work if your first file errors out, of course.

```
import dask.dataframe as dd
import dask.delayed

_default_record = None

def _read(self, filename):
    global _default_record
    try:
        df = pd.read_csv(filename, sep=';', decimal=',', encoding='latin1', index_col=False)
        if _default_record is None:
            _default_record = pd.DataFrame.from_items([
                        (name, pd.Series(data=None, dtype=series.dtype))
                              for name, series in df.head(1).iteritems()])
        return df
    except BaseException as e:
        return _default_record


tasks = []
for root, dirs, files in os.walk(os.path.join(self._path, "files")):
    for file in files:
        tasks.append(dask.delayed(_read, pure=True)(os.path.join(root, file)))

ddf = dd.from_delayed(tasks)
```

Comment: when I try this code, I get this error:
UnboundLocalError: local variable '_default_record' referenced before assignment
any ideas?

Answer (score 0):

Answer from @morganics Updated for what I'm assuming are newer versions of pandas(1.1.5) and dask (2020.12.0).

```
import dask.dataframe as dd
import dask.delayed
import pandas as pd

_default_record = None

def _read(self, filename):
    global _default_record
    try:
        df = pd.read_csv(filename, sep=';', decimal=',', encoding='latin1', index_col=False)
        if _default_record is None:
            _default_record = pd.DataFrame([
                        {name: pd.Series(data=None, dtype=series.dtype)
                              for name, series in df.head(1).iteritems()})
        return df
    except BaseException as e:
        return _default_record


tasks = []
for root, dirs, files in os.walk(os.path.join(self._path, "files")):
    for file in files:
        tasks.append(dask.delayed(_read, pure=True)(os.path.join(root, file)))

ddf = dd.from_delayed(tasks)
```

I made _default_record a global variable, and I removed the `from_items` method from the dataframe constructor, because it doesn't exist in my version of pandas.